# Aligning parallel ordered lists

Tags: html, css

I have two order lists with comparable information but list item contents may not have the same length. Due to wrapping, certain list items span different number of lines.

```
List 1        List 2
1. xxx        1. xxxxxxxx
2. xxxxxxxx      xxx
   xxx        2. xxxxxxxx
3. xxxxxxxx      xxxxxxxx
   xxx           xxx
4. xxxx       3. xxxx
              4. xxxx
```

Is there a way such that equal item labels are horizontally aligned (without resorting to using tables)?

```
List 1        List 2
1. xxx        1. xxxxxxxx
                 xxx
2. xxxxxxxx   2. xxxxxxxx
   xxx           xxxxxxxx
                 xxx
3. xxxxxxxx   3. xxxx
   xxx
4. xxxx       4. xxxx
```

Comment: short answer - no.. Those `<li>`-s are not related to each other in any way. Unless you use jQuery

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CSS just isn't equipped for this, unless you're content with making each `li` a fixed height.  Honestly, I think that if you're needing these aligned, your lists are related to each other, and really it is semantically a table.

Comment: Is it possible then to combine the two lists into one, each list item having two columns?